# Compilation error on MongoDB Casbah for Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I am wrting an update query on Scala and Cashbah. When I write this...

```
val query = MongoDBObject({"_id" -> uri.toString})

val update: DBObject =
  $set("uDate" -> new DateTime) ++
  $addToSet("appearsOn") $each(sourceToAppend:_*) ++
  $addToSet("hasElements") $each(elementsToAppend:_*) ++
  $addToSet("hasTriples") $each (triplesToAppend:_*)

OntologyDocument.dao.collection.update(query, update, upsert = true)
```

...it gives me a compilation error like this. But if I write it like this...

```
No implicit view available from Object{def $each(target: Array[Any]): com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Imports.DBObject; def $each(target: Any*): com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Imports.DBObject} => com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Imports.DBObject.
```

...then it compiles and runs successfully.

```
val query = MongoDBObject({"_id" -> uri.toString})

val setOps1 = $addToSet("appearsOn") $each(sourceToAppend:_*)
val setOps2 = $addToSet("hasElements") $each(elementsToAppend:_*)
val setOps3 = $addToSet("hasTriples") $each (triplesToAppend:_*)

val update: DBObject = $set("uDate" -> new DateTime) ++ setOps1 ++ setOps2 ++ setOps3

OntologyDocument.dao.collection.update(query, update, upsert = true)
```

I didn't get it.

**Why doesn't the first one compile, or the second one compiles?**

Am I missing a Scala basic?

Comment: What are the values of sourceToAppend, elementsToAppend and triplesToAppend?

Comment: They are `sourceToAppend: List[String]` `elementsToAppend: List[String]` and `triplesToAppend: List[ObjectId]` all defaults to `Nil`. `ObjectId` is `com.mongodb.casbah.commons.TypeImports#ObjectId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how the dsl is implemented and the chaining of `$each`.  The core issue is I dont think $addToSet merges as expected::

```
val setOps1 = $addToSet("appearsOn") $each(sourceToAppend:_*)
val setOps2 = $addToSet("hasElements") $each(elementsToAppend:_*)
setOps1 ++ setOps2

DBObject = { "$addToSet" : { "hasElements" : { "$each" : [ "another" , "list"]}}}
```

Seems MongoDBObject ++ does not recursively merge.